# Laravel throws 419 on a POST request with csrf token correct

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

I have a post request of user registeration in my laravel app and on submit of the form, it returns me 419 error. But when I include the route as an exception in the verifycsrf middleware, it works. But I do not want it in the exception.

I have the csrf token in the form as @csrf and SESSION driver is database. I have no SESSION_DOMAIN set. I have also checked for the appname_session cookie and its present.

After more debugging, I found that these 2 values are different in the controller on form submit and after adding the route in csrf exception

```
request()->session()->token()
```

and

```
request()->input('_token')
```

I'm using laravel 5.7 and php 7.1. How do I fix this?

Comment: Try on this way `<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />`

Comment: do you keep getting new records in the database on every page load? (for the sessions table)

Comment: @STA Should I put it inside the form or outside?

Comment: @Saeesh inside of form

Comment: @STA Still does not work. I had already checked the hidden _token field. It's present

Comment: @lagbox Yes it does add new record for every page load

Comment: that is why the session value will never match, it is creating a new session on every request ... usually a cookie issue

Comment: @lagbox What should I do about it? I'm guessing something is wrong in the config

Comment: stop serve  and  excute `php artisan config:clear` && `php artisan session:clear` thren rerun your artisan serve

Comment: @MortadaJafar Nah. Still get the same thing

Comment: if you don't want use csfr then check this doc how to disable it  -https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf

Comment: @Hamelraj I want to use the csrf. Read my question